# Embeddable or web servers requiring no installation

Tags: opencv, web, webserver

I am working on a c++/cli program that which records live video (I use OpenCV). Now I need to facilitate it with broadcast support where other people can watch it by using their web browser. As you know videos are sequence of images so I need the web page to get the new "frame" grabbed from the web cam and display it in web page in speed of 5 times in every 1 second (5fps). For this, in order to allow others to access the web page, I need a web server  (running in localhost is OK because connected machines can access it).

I am not up to web technologies so I have only used Apache Tomcat and Microsoft default server.But in both, you have to setup the server, upload the files to it and much more. But there are some programs like [this](http://www.digi-watcher.com/)  and [this](http://www.pysoft.com/) where they do not require such servers where you need to install and setup but still does the job. I think they are using embedded web servers.

So, are there are any servers like that which matches to my requirements? Please note my program is in c++/cli and I need to distribute the server with it as well, just like the above 2 programs do.

### Edit

Please note that I mentioned C++ / CLI just to give you a clear understanding about my system and not because I am seeking for a server with CGI script support or I m seeking for a server built with c++. If at least JavaScript can run there that is enough because I can update using it.

Comment: be bold, and write your own ? yes, it's difficult, but probably less than interfering with mammoths like apache. from your description, it seems, that a mjpg "stream" (it's actually jpg images interleaved with http-multipart) would do. you're actually just emulating an ip-cam.

Comment: replying to your edit : you've got a singleton there ( the VideoCapture ) cgi won't help you ( as it's called for multiple clients / threads )